# Example of borel measurable function for which there doesnot exist a borel set such that function restricted on it is continuous

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

Give an example of a Borel measurable function f from R to R such that there
does not exist a set B ⊂ R such that $| R \setminus B |$ = 0 and $f|_B$ is a continuous
function on B.
By Lusin's theorem there always exist a closed set F such that $f|_F$  is continuous and $|R\setminus F| <\epsilon$. So if $F_{n}$ is chosen in such a way that $|R\setminus F| < 1/n$ and B is taken to be the union of all such sets, then $| R \setminus B |$ = 0 .So the question narrows down to finding an example where it is continuous on each $F_{n}$ but not on its union.

Comment: Do you know about generalized Cantor sets?

Comment: No. (/*just to satisfy the number of characters criteria*/)

Comment: Then now is your chance to look them up, because the indicator function of such a set will provide your example.  The key is that such a set is closed, has empty interior, and has positive measure.